# pm2 does not run the build on VITE

Tags: reactjs, vite, pm2

I tried to build the project on Vite (npm run build)
And run it on port 3003 (npx run preview) because the other ports are busy

But pm2 is constantly updating my build

What could be the problem? Before that, I collected only Next projects and everything was fine, but there were some difficulties with Vite

vite.confing.ts

```
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
    import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [react()],
    })
```

Tried:

```
git clone 'project_name'
npm i
npm run build
pm2 start npx --name 'name' -- preview
```

Status of pm2:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: `vite-app`,
      script: "serve",
      env: {
        PM2_SERVE_PATH: "./dist",
        PM2_SERVE_PORT: 5173,
        PM2_SERVE_SPA: "true",
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

and then  npm run build

```
"build": "tsc && vite build && pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production"
```

Comment: I have a problem of 'module' is not defined with ES6